# Flutter installation

Tags: flutter

I have installed everything, but it is not debugging.

> Exception: unable to find suitable visual studio toolchain. Please run 'flutter run' for more results

Comment: Can we safely assume you've tried `flutter run`? What happens when you do?

Comment: Re *"debugging"*: As in not fixing the problem, not actual program debugging?